# LilyPond – omit first page-number when numbering formatted by markup

Tags: lilypond, engraving

I use this snippet to reformat the [LilyPond](http://www.lilypond.org) page numbering:

```
pagenumcol = \markup {
  \column {
    \vspace #0.5
    \fromproperty #'page:page-number-string
  }
}

copyrightcol = \markup {
  \fill-line {
    \box \fontsize #-4
    \column {
      \line { "Educational copying welcome." }
    }
  }
}

\paper {
  oddHeaderMarkup = \markup \null
  evenHeaderMarkup = \markup \null
  oddFooterMarkup = \markup { \copyrightcol \pagenumcol }
  evenFooterMarkup = \markup { \pagenumcol \copyrightcol }
}
```

When using this example the first page number gets printed. Does anyone on here know how I can omit this?

I tried to add `print-first-page-number = ##f`, but it does not take any effect in this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the page number is not printed on the first page, so adding `print-first-page-number = ##f` won’t change the default setting.

Rather, you first need to check whether LilyPond would by default print the page number on the relevant page. This can be done with `\on-the-fly #print-page-number-check-first` (see also the [relevant section in the LilyPond documentation on customised footers and headers](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/custom-headers-footers-and-titles#custom-layout-for-headers-and-footers)).

This way, you re-activate the default behaviour of not printing the page number on the first page, which you overrode by defining your custom footer.

The following settings should work:

```
pagenumcol = \markup {
  \column {
    \vspace #0.5
    \fromproperty #'page:page-number-string
  }
}

copyrightcol = \markup {
  \fill-line {
    \box \fontsize #-4
    \column {
      \line { "Educational copying welcome." }
    }
  }
}

\paper {
  oddHeaderMarkup = \markup \null
  evenHeaderMarkup = \markup \null
  oddFooterMarkup = \markup { \copyrightcol \on-the-fly #print-page-number-check-first \pagenumcol }
  evenFooterMarkup = \markup { \on-the-fly #print-page-number-check-first \pagenumcol \copyrightcol }
}
```